# How do I migrate, and rename a computer using ADMT command line?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, migration, admt, accounts

I've checked all the ADMT documentation, experimented with negative results and am unable to get ADMT to rename a computer during a migration.

The command I'm using is:

```
C:\admt>admt computer /f:c:\admt\computers2.txt /sd:psg.local /td:company.com 
/to:"Division"  /sdc:wpdc01 /tdc:nycdc03 /pre:no 
/tot:add /tff:yes /tlg:yes /tps:yes /trg:yes  /tss:yes /tup:yes /tur:yes  
/co:merge 
/rdl:5 /prrtry:yes /prrtryi:1 /prrtryn:60    /portry:yes  /portryi:1  /portryn:60
```

The file computers2.txt has a list of computer names; like this:

```
Sourcename, TargetSAM
oldName, $NewName
```

Any assistance in setting this up to rename a computer upon a migration would be a great help.

I tried the online documentation, and it is obviously in error because it says to use the `/o`
option to migrate a list of computers in a txt file, when the correct parameter is `/f`

Comment: meh, a downvote on an on topic question like this with no explanation is relevant to much discussion on meta.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't rename computers using the ADMT agent.  That would be a nice feature request though.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974436(v=ws.10).aspx